# Unzip folder in Windows Azure Blob Storage

Tags: unzip, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I've read you can upload an application such as winzip to your blob storage to unzip a folder stored in blob storage, my question is how would I go about doing this also where would the contents of the folder be extracted too?

Comment: Do you remember where you read it?  I'm sure you could upload winzip and store it in blob storage, but unless you pull it out of blob storage I don't see how you could execute it.  I'd love to know where you heard about it.

Answer (score 1):

U can download the zip blob as **Stream** then u extract that stream and then only you can Upload the files in windows Azure...

steps have to follow :

1. First download the zip as stream
2. Unzip the zip file using that stream
3. Upload that again as u wish

Answer (score 0):

This must have been some missleading information, or you didn't understand it. There is no way you can execute a process in the Windows Azure Blob storage. It is Storage Service, not a process execution engine, nor operating system.

You certainly can upload any files in Windows Azure Blob storage, but you cannot execute them there. You can only execute files (i.e. lauch a process) in a Windows Azure Roles (Web or Worker or VM). You could have your own process running in a Worker or Web Role, which expects a ZIP package, then unzip it locally, then upload all the files in the Windows Azure Blob storage. But you cannot have that process itself running in a Windows Azure Storage service.